# Interpolation error (proof)

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation, error-function

Does anyone know how this is proven?

The function $f(x)=0,2x^5$ is given. Prove that for an interpolation polynomial $p_4(x)$  that interpolates a function $f(x)$ at nodes $x_0=0$, $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=3$, $y_4=4$, the following estimate is valid:

[image]

The following hint is also given, which can be used without proof:

[image]

I'm assuming this is an interpolation error. I don't understand at all what needs to be applied for this proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Newton divided differences, you have
$$
f(x)=\begin{aligned}[t]f(x_0)&+f[x_0,x_1](x-x_0)\\
&+f[x_0,x_1,x_2](x-x_0)(x-x_1)\\
&+f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3](x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\\
&+f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4](x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)\\
&+f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x](x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)\\
\end{aligned}
\\
=P_4(x)+\frac1{5!}f^{(5)}(\xi)(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)
$$
You should be able to combine the given hints into the claimed inequality.